# How to get rid of namespace when marshaling generic objects with JAXB

Tags: java, serialization, jaxb, xml-namespaces

I use the following code to serialize a class:

```
public String serialize(T oObject)
{
    mMarshaller = getJAXBContext().createMarshaller();
    mMarshaller.setProperty(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    ByteArrayOutputStream strm = getOutputStream();
    mMarshaller.marshal(oObject, strm);
    return strm.toString();
}
```

But when I look at the generaetd XML there is a namespace in there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<mapEntry>
    <key xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">
    Key
    </key>
    <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">
     oValue
     </value>
 </mapEntry>
```

Is there some way to remove this, or tell JAXB that it should NOT add this? I'm looking at this now the whole morning and tried several things I found via google, but nothing helped.

Now I found this thread here: [How to marshal without a namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816176/jaxb-how-to-marshal-without-a-namespace) but the problem is that the accepted answer is only partially listed and now I don't know if this would help me. `XMLStreamWriter` is an interface, and I don't want to implement a whole stream writer just for that. So is there some way to extend the `ByteArrayOutputStream` without the need of implementing all the other functions, such an XMLWriter would need?

Answer (score 2):

In this use case the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` and `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` namespaces are being brought in because of the `xsi:type` attribute.  The `xsi:type` attribute is being brought in because your JAXB implementation believes the property type to be `Object`.  The solution is to ensure the properties aren't typed `Object`.

The XML representation looks like part of the representation for `java.util.Map` (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/jaxb-and-javautilmap.html).  Is this your use case or do you have another object model?

Comment: I have a class which implements the `java.util.Map.Entry<K, V>`, so I guess the problem is because of the generic types, right? Then how can I do this with generic objects?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Looks like it's because of `Generic` type.