# Namespace with no prefix in JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, xml-namespaces

I am trying to create a [Sitemap index](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) file with JAXB. Following the requirements for creating the sitemap, I have to add the namespace attribute in the root element:

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```

I would like to have a simple way to sort this out. Since this seems to be a standard procedure I would like to not do a [complex workaround or add more dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816176/how-to-marshal-without-a-namespace/38096137#38096137) to my project in order to solve this issue

The current output is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:sitemapindex xmlns:ns2="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <sitemap>
        <loc>https://www.example.com/sitemap-1.xml</loc>
        <lastmod>2017-05-01T15:41:17.561+01:00</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
</ns2:sitemapindex>
```

My `SitemapIndex` model is the following:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "sitemapindex", namespace="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SitemapIndex {

    @XmlElement(name = "sitemap")
    private List<Sitemap> sitemaps;

    public void setSitemaps(List<Sitemap> sitemaps) {
        this.sitemaps = sitemaps;
    }

    public List<Sitemap> getSitemaps() {
        return sitemaps;
    }
}
```

I have also tried to add the namespace field manually and it works for generating the file but I an exception is thrown when I try to read the file.

```
@XmlAttribute(name="xmlns")
private final String namespace ="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `@XmlSchema` [1] package level annotation in order to set prefix. In your case, we just set empty prefix.

Simply create `package-info.java` file in your package e.g. `com.stackoverflow.jaxb`, with similar content.

*package-info.java*

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9",
           xmlns = {@XmlNs(prefix = "",
                           namespaceURI = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9")},
           elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.stackoverflow.jaxb;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

Note, that you can remove `namespace` attribute from `@XmlRootElement` annotation.

---

[1] https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html

Comment: Thank you for the advice. This solution makes me to have a different package for each model with a different schema. Anyway I think It is the most suitable solution for my problem