# @XmlElementWrapper generating empty list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jaxb

I'm using JAXB to unmarshal some http client response with Spring Boot 3.0.8 & Java 17,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I use `@XmlElementWrapper`, I get empty list

here is the complete code :

foo.xml

```
<foo xmlns='my-secret-name-space' name='hello'>
    <bars>
        <bar name='hello bar 1'/>
        <bar name='hello bar 2'/>
    </bars>
</foo>
```

Foo.java

```
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.List;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@XmlRootElement(name = "foo", namespace = "my-secret-name-space")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

  @XmlAttribute private String name;


  @XmlElementWrapper(name = "bars", namespace = "my-secret-name-space")
  @XmlElement(name = "bar")
  private List<Bar> bars;

}
```

Bar.java

```
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Bar {

  @XmlAttribute private String name;

}
```

unmarshling code

```
try (InputStream inputStream = getSomeInputStream()) {
  JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);
  return (Foo) context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(inputStream);
}
```

in my Foo class i got the name attribute correctly initialized, but the bars list is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are simply missing the namespace on the `@XmlElement` for `bar`.

For me, it worked as expected, when I added that:

```java
@Data
@XmlRootElement(name = "foo", namespace = "http://ns.fredhopper.com/XML/output/6.1.0")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

    @XmlAttribute private String name;
    
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "bars", namespace = "http://ns.fredhopper.com/XML/output/6.1.0")
    @XmlElement(name = "bar", namespace = "http://ns.fredhopper.com/XML/output/6.1.0")
    private List<Bar> bars;
}
```

And I used the `Foo.class` when creating the `JAXBContext`:

```java
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);
foo = (Foo) context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(inputStream);
```

Comment: yeah thanks man that was the root cause, but is there some is there some setting to set the namespace globally ?

Comment: I found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721186/namespace-with-no-prefix-in-jaxb - you just have to create a package-info.java for your Jaxb-Classes and configure the namespace at package level.  @XmlSchema(namespace = "http://ns.fredhopper.com/XML/output/6.1.0",
        elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED
)
- that did the trick for me.