How to parse a subpart of an XML file as raw XML using JAXB without including namespaces in tags?
My problem is that I have an .xml file of this kind to parse :
item.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/item ../../item.xsd"
      xmlns="http://www.example.com/item">
    <ID>1234</ID>
    <ItemDescription kind="long">
        <p>
            <u>This is a description</u>
        </p>
        <br/>
        <p>End Of description</p>
    </ItemDescription>
    <ItemDescription kind="short">
        <p>
            <u>This is a description</u>
        </p>
    </ItemDescription>
</Item>

I want every part of the document to be mapped to java Class, except what is under ItemDescription. Everything under ItemDescription should be store as String including the tag, it should be considered as raw XML.
I have tried several approach and my major issue is that the namespace of the xml get included into the tags "p" and "br" and I don't want that.
The only way I have succeed fixing that is using regex, but I want a solution in which they didn't get added.
Here is a code sample that get the job done while still having the namespace in it :
Item.java
package org.example;

import org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.List;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Item", namespace = "http://www.example.com/item")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item {

    @XmlElement(name = "ID", namespace = "http://www.example.com/item")
    private String id;

    @XmlElement(name = "ItemDescription", namespace = "http://www.example.com/item")
    private List<ItemDescription> itemDescriptions;

    // Getters and Setters
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<ItemDescription> getItemDescriptions() {
        return itemDescriptions;
    }

    public void setItemDescriptions(List<ItemDescription> itemDescriptions) {
        this.itemDescriptions = itemDescriptions;
    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public static class ItemDescription {

        @XmlAttribute(name = "kind")
        private String kind;

        // Store raw XML content as a String
        @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
        private List<org.w3c.dom.Element> elements;

        // Getters and Setters
        public String getKind() {
            return kind;
        }

        public void setKind(String kind) {
            this.kind = kind;
        }

        public List<Element> getElements() {
            return elements;
        }

        public void setElements(List<Element> elements) {
            this.elements = elements;
        }

        public String getElementsAsString() {
            if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(elements)) {
                return "";
            }

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (Object element : elements) {
                // Check if the element is an instance of a JAXB element that can be converted to XML
                if (element != null) {
                    sb.append(element.toString());
                }
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public String getContentAsString() {
            if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(elements)) {
                return "";
            }
            StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
            for (Element element : elements) {
                // Create a new document to hold the element without namespaces
                DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
                try {
                    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document doc = builder.newDocument();
                    Node importedNode = doc.importNode(element, true);
                    doc.appendChild(importedNode);

                    // Convert the document to a string
                    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
                    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
                    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
                    content.append(writer);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return content.toString();
        }

    }
}

ItemParser.java
package org.example;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class ItemParser {

public void doParse(String resourcePath) throws JAXBException {
    // Initialize JAXB context
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Item.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

    // Load XML from resources
    InputStream xmlStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourcePath);
    if (xmlStream == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("File not found: " + resourcePath);
    }

    // Parse XML into Item object
    Item item = (Item) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStream);
    System.out.println("ID: " + item.getId());

    // Print descriptions with raw XML content
    if (item.getItemDescriptions() != null) {
        for (Item.ItemDescription description : item.getItemDescriptions()) {
            System.out.println("Raw XML Content: " + description.getContentAsString());
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new ItemParser().doParse("item.xml");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ItemParser</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>

Output of main in ItemParser.java
ID: 1234
Raw XML Content: <p xmlns="http://www.example.com/item" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><u>This is a description</u>
        </p><br xmlns="http://www.example.com/item" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/><p xmlns="http://www.example.com/item" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">End Of description</p>
Raw XML Content: <p xmlns="http://www.example.com/item" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><u>This is a description</u>
        </p>

As you can see the namespace of the document get added into the tags.
What I have try

regex to get rid of the xmlns attribute -> it's working but not clean

Use Transformer but there is not property similar to OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION for namespaces.

Use DOM API to remove attribute starting with "xmlns" using Element.removeAttribute. Removing the attributes work well but they get added back when serialising the element to a String using the transformer. I think this is because the Element still have a field "namespaceURI" that is not exposed through the API.

Same that the bullet point before but on a cloned element (just in case the clone could miss the namespace but no)

I have try to have a String in the ItemDescription entity class and to have a custom Adapter, but I did not suceed. I think if the entity class directly have a String field that map the raw XML as String, this will be the best solution


I precise that I only want to remove namespace attribute. If the original file has some other attribute I want to keep them.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29945934/2834978

This is not working as in my case the namespace comes from the document , I can't remove @XmlElement(name="", namespace"http://...") as the response says to do, else I won't parse the element at all.  This answer is only for generating XML using Jaxb not reading one.

In that case you could have another domain object without namespaces to convert xml to string.

I can manually  copy (or directly serialize them as String) each elements of the List but that's not clean at all. Other entity object does not answer the problem since if I copy the List it keep the namespace in it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2148541/2834978

I would start by transforming the document using XSLT before loading it into Jsvs using JAXB.

I think what you really need is to add xmlns="" to each ItemDescription element.  For example:  <ns:ItemDescription xmlns:ns="http://www.example.com/item" xmlns="" kind="long">  Without that, <p> is actually an element whose QName is {http://www.example.com/item}p.  Alas, there doesn’t seem to be a way to do that using XSLT 1.0 (which is the only version supported by the javax.xml.transform package).

You mentioned using a Transformer.  I’m not sure if this is what you’re looking for, but… you can strip the namespace from every element by creating an element in its place which uses its local-name but has no namespace:
// Convert the document to a string
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(
    new StreamSource(new StringReader("""
        <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
            <xsl:output method="xml"/>
            <xsl:template match="//*">
                <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:template>
            <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
    """)));

